# How to access object keys names in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-in-loop

```
console.log(answerKey);

for(singleKey in answerKey){
     
}
```

answerKey is my object. Can anybody please tell that how can I access object key names and values.
Please see the screenshot (https://prnt.sc/nKTfE4GzoCMW)

Answer (score 2):

To access the keys and values separately, you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) methods separately.

```js
const answerKey = {
  key1: 'answer1',
  key2: 'answer2',
  key3: 'answer3',
  key4: 'answer4',
  key5: 'answer5'
};

console.log(Object.keys(answerKey));

console.log(Object.values(answerKey));
```

If you want to access together, you can either iterate over the `Object.keys()` or you can also use the inbuilt [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method.

```js
const answerKey = {
  key1: 'answer1',
  key2: 'answer2',
  key3: 'answer3',
  key4: 'answer4',
  key5: 'answer5'
};

console.log(Object.entries(answerKey));

Object.keys(answerKey).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key, answerKey[key]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it by using this

```
for(singleKey in answerKey){
     console.log(Object.keys(answerKey[singleKey])[0]); 
}
```